# Set interval to a function don´t works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented push notification to my project, so I have a bootstrap alert who can change content at every time. As default it comes empty, so I have a function who hide alert if it comes empty and check every 3 seconds if have new content

Problem is when it get content it don't show up notification

```js
setInterval(function() {
  hideAlert("a1");
}, 3000);

function hideAlert(id) {
  var text = $('#' + id + ' #discussion').text();
  if (text.length <= 0)
    $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

```css
#a1 { border: 1px solid red; }
#discussion { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1" class="alert alert-success">
  <div id="discussion" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE: I dont reload page to get value into alert, I can get value at any moment, that´s why I use setInterval but it don´t works

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet. It appears to work absolutely fine. Could you check the console in your version for errors

Comment: Note that a selector like `#a1 #decision` is most likely going to be treated exactly like `#decision`, since id values have to be unique across the document.

Comment: I feel, he meants when he putting value its not again visible? is it? that case you have to handle either from where you are adding text or from the the same interval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just hiding it, not showing it again. You should show the notification **when a new response is received**.

```js
// interval for checking status again and again
setInterval(function() {
  checkAlertStatus("a1");
}, 500);

// check status at first
checkAlertStatus("a1");

// function to check status (show or hide alert)
function checkAlertStatus(id) {
  var text = $('#' + id + ' #discussion').text();
  if (text.length <= 0)
    $('#' + id).hide();
  else 
    $('#' + id).show();
}

// simulate receiving text from websocket or ajax request
setTimeout(function () { $('#discussion').text('Hello Notification'); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function () { $('#discussion').text(''); }, 2000);
setTimeout(function () { $('#discussion').text('Another reponse'); }, 3000);
```

```css
#a1 { border: 1px solid red; }
#discussion { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1" class="alert alert-success">
  <div id="discussion" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```